# $2\pi$ in the Definition of Fourier Transform

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Most textbooks I read define Fourier transform of a function $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ as

$$
\hat f (\xi) := \int_\mathbb R f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \xi} dx.
$$

However, in class my teacher defines it without the $2\pi$. My question is whether this $2\pi$ is necessary and what role does it play here? Thank you!

Comment: In general, the Fourier transform may be defined using two arbitrary constants $a$ and $b$ as
[$$
F(\omega)=\sqrt{\frac{|b|}{(2\pi)^{1-a}}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{ib\omega t}\ dt
$$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a factor for norming. See [the wikipedia article on Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) for a list of common constants. The one I see more often uses
$$\hat f(\xi) := (2\pi)^{-\frac n2} \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x) e^{-ix\cdot \xi} \mathrm dx \\
\check f(x) = (2\pi)^{-\frac n2} \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(\xi) e^{ix\cdot \xi} \mathrm d\xi$$
Where $\cdot$ denotes the inner product. Both of these are isometric isomorphisms on $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$.
Possible advantages of the two choices are only in constants in the convolution theorem (my version is $\widehat{f\ast g}(\xi) = (2\pi)^n \hat f(\xi) \hat g(\xi)$) and easier (constant-less) partial integration and differentiation for my version:
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\xi} \hat f(\xi) = i\xi \widehat{f'}(\xi)$$

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible conventions, but you can't get around the fact that a $2\pi$ will appear somewhere.
In order to have a way of comparing different conventions easily, I wrote up [restrictions on the various coefficients in the definitions and comparison between different choices](http://users.jyu.fi/~jojapeil/mat/fourier.pdf).